# Sort data using entity model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to sort different field. i.e. blogID, date, author
I found order by method but dont know how to pass the value in the method... help please

```
public List<blog> BlogFetch(string key)
{
    List<blog> blogRes = new List<blog>();

    using (var be = new BlogEntities())
    {
        blog res = new blog();

        foreach (var User in be.blogs.OrderBy(<what goes here?>))
        {
            res = User;
            blogRes.Add(res);
        }
    }
    return blogRes;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
be.blogs.OrderBy(b => b.NameOfPropertyOnBlogClass)
```

It's a [Lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) which is used heavily in LINQ.  [Here's](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) a good "cheatsheet" on getting started with LINQ syntax.

As an aside if you want to load a List of items when using EF you can just call `ToList()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `OrderBy` method takes a function with the following signature:

```
TResult PropertyRetrieval<TInput, TResult>(TInput obj);
```

So, if you have a Blog and you want to sort by BlogID, the result will be this (assuming BlogID is an int):

```
int SortBy(Blog obj)
{
    return obj.BlogId;
}
```

You can enter this by a Lambda expression:

```
be.blogs.OrderBy(blog => blog.BlogID); 
be.blogs.OrderBy(blog => blog.Date);
be.blogs.OrderBy(blog => blog.Author);
```

etc.